# Laravel Dropzone.js some photos cannot be saved into the folder

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to allow the users to upload multiple photos to the database. Before I set up the database for the image uploader feature, I wanted to see if the image can be saved into my desired folder. However, after successfully uploading 3 photos(since the tick logo was shown right after the image was uploaded, I assumed the image has been successfully uploaded), only 2 of them were present in the folder.

In the following codes I have listed the view(including javascript and html codes), route and controller file:

**CSS ->**

```
{{html::style('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.css')}}
```

**HTML ->**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'gallery.images.upload', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data','files' => true, 'id' => 'addImages', 'method' => "POST")) !!}

  {{ Form::hidden('gallery_id', $gallery->id) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Javascript ->**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.addImages = {
        maxFilesize: 5,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
        paramName: "file",
    }
</script>
```

**Route ->**

```
Route::prefix('gallery')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/images/upload', 'GalleryController@uploadGalleryImages')->name('gallery.images.upload');
});
```

**Controller ->**

```
public function uploadGalleryImages(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

        // Get the file from the file request
        $file = $request->file('file');

        // set my file name
        $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $filename = uniqid() . $originalName;

        $file->move('galleries/images/', $filename);

    } 
    else{
        return redirect()->route('gallery.view');
    }
}
```

I have been asking around for several weeks but couldn't get any answer. I really need your help!

[Screenshot of images being successfully uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYaWO.jpg)

[Screenshot of images present in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyDVn.jpg)

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: @AndyHolmes In the console it showed me this:
`[Violation] 'load' handler took 151ms       dropzone.min.js:1`

Comment: @AndyHomes Sometimes it will show this : `[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 34ms`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once because the server when going through the images it overwrites some images because they get the same filename, to avoid this use something like this to make sure you have unique filenames:

```
$random = mt_rand(1,1000);
$filename  = time().''.$random. '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: Did you see the `$filename = uniqid() . $originalName;`?

Comment: Yes, it might be something with the uniqueid() function, try to add time with a random value, to make sure its unique.

Comment: @Sletheren Thanks for your reply. The problem remained the same when I change the uniqid() function to the lines given in your comment.